# Call inline block specifying return Type and Parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I've decided to try to use blocks for control flow in Objective-C and am running into some issues with calling multiple blocks inline.

I've got an OOBoolean which is a wrapper to a BOOL primitive, and provides these methods:

```
+ (id) booleanWithBool: (BOOL) boolPrimitive;

- (id) initWithBool: (BOOL) boolPrimitive;

- (void) ifTrueDo: (void (^) ()) trueBlock 
        ifFalseDo: (void (^) ()) falseBlock;

- (void) ifTrueDo: (void (^) ()) trueBlock;

- (void) ifFalseDo: (void (^) ()) falseBlock;
```

I have no problem using this class like so:

```
OOBoolean* condition = [OOBoolean booleanWithBool: (1 + 1 == 2)];

id trueBlock = ^(){
    NSLog(@"True.");
};

id falseBlock = ^(){
    NSLog(@"False.");
};

[condition ifTrueDo: trueBlock ifFalseDo: falseBlock];
```

And I get a result of "True.". But I keep getting syntax errors when trying this instead:

```
OOBoolean* condition = [OOBoolean booleanWithBool: (1 + 1 == 2)];

[condition ifTrueDo:(void (^)()) {
    NSLog(@"True");
} ifFalseDo:(void (^)()) {
    NSLog(@"False");
}];
```

Is it not possible to define multiple blocks anonymously and pass them to a method that takes multiple block arguments? If so, that's kind of a let down.

Comment: Interesting idea, though I'm thinking this is much less efficient at runtime than having the compiler optimize conditionals for you.

Comment: I'm actually interested in understanding the efficiency differences here. Clearly this is less efficient due to the additional message send, and I understand there's some performance considerations with blocks and enclosing variables outside  ifTrue ifFalse message call, but I'm curious how much of an impact this would really have.

Comment: The easiest way to think about this is to consider how many stack frames you're pushing.  The more stack frame you have the less efficient your code is (probably).  I don't know a lot about compiler theory but I can guess that using the standard `if() else` construct results in optimized program flow using certain options at compile time.

Comment: Are you familiar with other languages that do this? Do you know if there are similar performance penalties in those? I'm thinking Smalltalk specifically, but I wonder if compiler optimizations could be done for this format as well (which I imagine they must be in something like Smalltalk since it's the only way of doing control flow). I have to admit I'm very ignorant on the implementation issues as well, I just like the style.

Comment: I can't comment on Smalltalk (I _knew_ you were going to mention Smalltalk) but any compiler worth its salt knows how to identify hotspots in code and common decision structure optimizations, like unrolling loops. IMHO, I think the Objective C compiler won't be able to optimize your OOBoolean class behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible.

You simply had way too many parentheses in there.  Try this:

`[condition ifTrueDo:^() { NSLog(@"True"); }
         ifFalseDo:^() { NSLog(@"False"); }
     ];`

EDIT:
Your block syntax is slightly incorrect.

If you want to include return  type and parameters, you should use something closer to this:

`[self ifTrueDo:^ void (void) { NSLog(@"True"); }
         ifFalseDo:^ void (void) { NSLog(@"False"); }
     ];`

In english:

`^ [return type] ([parameter list]) {[block content]}`

Comment: Interesting. So if you don't use the verbose block definition style ( ^() { block code } ) it works fine. But doing void (^)() { block code} is a no-go? The first option works fine for my case, but I thought you could optionally also give the block return type and parameters (none in this case) when specifying the block.

Comment: Updated answer to include block syntax.

Comment: You win.  ;)  I couldn't figure out how to explicitly set the return type when defining it.  I've never done that.  I usually let the compiler infer the return type.  Also, I tried your syntax of explicitly setting the return type and it does compile.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Mixed up the method parameter definition and inline specification style for blocks.

Comment: @donalbain The problem with the original code was a missing `^` before the first curly-brace. `(void(^)()) { NSLog(...); }` should have been `(void(^)()) ^{ NSLog(...); }`. All these other suggestions, while being excellent stylistic advice, didn't actually point out the specific typo that caused you so much confusion. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your method declaration expects a block returning void (nothing):

```
- (void) ifTrueDo: (void (^) ()) trueBlock 
        ifFalseDo: (void (^) ()) falseBlock;
```

However, you later call this passing in blocks with the signature of (id^()()):

```
[condition ifTrueDo:(id (^)()) {
    NSLog(@"True");
}         ifFalseDo:(id (^)()) {
    NSLog(@"False");
}];
```

Just get rid of the "id" part like the following - note: and I tried this and it compiles without warnings:

```
[condition ifTrueDo:^{
          NSLog(@"True");
     }
     ifFalseDo:^{
          NSLog(@"False");
     }
 ];
```

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to change the id to void before posting the code. The current code should now be reflected.

Comment: Yep, that sure does. I think my question is why it doesn't compile when you additionally specify the block return type and block params inline. So [condition ifTrueDo:(void)(^)(){ NSLog(@"True");...] doesn't compile.